# What are different types of fibre cable?

Tags: networking, cable, optical-cable

I am looking forward to use SFP port (not SFP+).
Right now I understand there are 4 types of module.

- Single Mode SFP
- Multi-Mode SFP
- Single Mode SFP (BiDi)
- Multi-Mode SFP (BiDi)

For all of these modules, do they use the same type of cable? Is fibre optic just fibre optic cable? there is no such thing as CAT5, CAT6E, CAT6A stuff like ethernet cable?

Thanks!

Comment: The current information on this topic is available in simple Google searches. I suggest you use them. Wikipedia is a good place to start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber_cable

Comment: But to put it briefly: No, there are many different types of fiber cable depending on your needs, the environment the cable will be running through, the length of the cable run, and other factors.

Comment: Many differences, generally multi-mode is a low quality plastic for the optical strands, usually with a 2km limit. Multi-mode sfp's are also cheaper because they use high intensity LEDs instead of lasers. Single-mode is usually high quality glass optical strands, with a limit of 10km+. The sfp's are usually more expensive because they have lasers and high-quality infrared sensors. (Strict bend radius requirements also)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could figure it out myself:

There are two main fiber *cable* types used for networking:

- [Single-mode fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-mode_optical_fiber) has a thinner core (around 8 µm); due to light travelling directly, it's suitable for very long distances, but somewhat more expensive to make (both the cables and the transceivers).
- [Multi-mode fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-mode_optical_fiber) has a wider core (50–65 µm); cheaper but short-distance only (up to 550 m at 1 Gbps, according to the Wikipedia table).

Both kinds have "categories", e.g. OM1–OM5 for multi-mode fiber.

Generally the cable type (SM or MM) needs to match the transceiver type, although SM modules can use MM fiber through a mode-conditioning patch cord (here's a [Cisco article with pictures](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/product_bulletin_c25-530836.html)).

Both "regular" and "BiDi" modules use the same type of fiber, the difference is whether a single connection needs two fiber strands (one in each direction), or just one (different colors/frequencies in each direction). For that reason BiDi modules need to be paired (e.g. a 1310/1550 nm module on one end, 1550/1310 on the other end).

Comment: "Both "regular" and "BiDi" modules use the same type of fiber" Just want to confirm again. Now the guy selling me the BiDi module is saying I need to care about the type of fiber, depending on whether it is FTTX or FTTH. Is this (FTTX and FTTH) a type of fiber optic cable?

Comment: @Zanko: No, it's a type of service (fiber to the house, etc.), but it frequently uses very different modules (GPON instead of Ethernet), slightly different connectors (SC/APC instead of SC/UPC) and _might_ also be using a different fiber type as well, I'm not sure. If you're making a point-to-point connection with your own hardware on both ends, I'd say "No, it's for a LAN."